# I want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$ is not first countable.

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

I don't understand the hint which is similar to the case in  $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in box topology.
Is there a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$ which does not satisfy the converse of sequence lemma?
Or just can find a point directly which is not countable local basis?
I tried to think about these method, but it is so hard to me, unlike the case of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in box topology.
I need your help.

Comment: You can use the same argument as that used to show that $\mathbb R^\omega$ is not first countable.

Comment: That argument is maybe using the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ consisting of those points all of whose coordinates are positive, but in $\mathbb{Q}^{\infty}$, the subset is empty, so I can't use that. Which subset can I use for the  same argument?

Comment: That subset is *not* empty at all. $\Bbb Q$ has plenty of positive values!

Answer (score 2):

The same proof and subset as for $\Bbb R^\infty$ (for the sequence lemma) work.

Let $A = \{(q_n) \in \Bbb Q^\infty: \forall n: q_n >0\}$ is a subset of $\Bbb Q^\infty$ that has $\underline{0} = (0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ as a point in its closure (a limit point even): if $\prod_n U_n$ is an open box-neighbourhood of $\underline{0}$, then each $U_n$ is open in $\Bbb Q$, containing $0$ so it contains some rational $q_n=\frac{1}{k}>0$ for $k$ large enough, say. Then $(q_n)_n \in (\prod_n U_n) \cap A $ so that $\underline{0} \in \overline{A}$.

But if $\left((q^{(m)}_n)_n\right)_m$ is a sequence in $A$, the product neighbourhood

$$\prod_n (-\frac{q^{(n)}_n}{2},  \frac{q^{(n)}_n}{2})$$ of $\underline{0}$ contains *no* members of that sequence so it cannot converge to $\underline{0}$.

This contradicts the sequence lemma and $\Bbb Q^\infty$ is not first countable.

Comment: Thanks to answer to my question.
but... I didn't yet understand that the subset A of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ is not empty...T.T
What I understood about $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ is that all component of element of the space are zero but finitely many components. but the subset A has points whose component has not zero. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: @algebraictopology no, $A$ is all sequences of rationals that are all strictly positive. $\Bbb Q^\infty$ has the box topology, of course. So $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ is in $ A$. Non-emptyness is clear.